# ANDROID, RETROFIT: Pressing back button during API call crashes the app

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am working with Retrofit to call REST API in my android app. To call an API, I use the code similar to this:

```
private void saveAddress(){
    // check if internet is available
    if(InternetUtil.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isOnline()) {
        if(validator.validate()) {
            showLoader();

            CustomerAPI customerAPI =
                    HttpClient.getClient().create(CustomerAPI.class);

            Call<HashMap<String, String>> call = customerAPI.createAddress(address);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<HashMap<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<HashMap<String, String>> call, Response<HashMap<String, String>> response) {
                    canGoBack = true;
                    HashMap<String, String> resultMap = response.body();

                    if (resultMap.get(Constant.CREATE_OPERATION_RESPONSE_KEY).equals(Constant.ADDRESS_CREATED_RESPONSE_VALUE)) {
                        hideLoader();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<HashMap<String, String>> call, Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println(t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }else{
        DialogUtil.showNoInternetDialog(this);
    }
}
```

I handled hardware back like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Go back to previous activity
 */
private void goBack(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddAddressActivity.this, AddressListActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

The problem is, when I click on Save Address button, API is called. If, in between, someone presses hardware back button, my app crashes.

One way to handle is to introduce a boolean variable like **canGoBack**. Before API is called, I can set it to false and after response is received, I can set it to true.
Then I have to change goBack like this:

```
private void goBack(){
    if(canGoBack){
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddAddressActivity.this, AddressListActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I feel the above code is not in best practices (only jugaad) and there must be a better way of doing this.

Also, when somebody presses home button during the call?

Comment: That's not how you handle the back button.  You override onBackPressed.  

Also, do not post "this crashed" without posting the full stack trace.

Comment: Also, your idea is absolutely backwards.  You do not stop a user from going back because you have some API call pending.  Instead you check if the activity has been finished and avoid the behavior that would crash you in that case.

Comment: Actually, I also have a back button, clicking on which also calls goBack, I'll also post stack trace

Comment: Then having onBackPressed and that button both call goBack is ok.  But you still don't treat the back button as if it was a normal hardware button.

Comment: Try not to call intent on back press, rather call onBackPressed with finish.

Answer (score 1):

That's because API calls execute asynchronously. When screen is dismissed while calling API, the calls are still being executed and the response is obtained in `onResponse` method of the class. It'll have the null values as the activity is destroyed. Try cancelling the API call in `onBackPressed` method. Better way will be using this code in `onStop` method.

```
if(call!=null)
call.cancel()
```